# VB.Net Application that reads sql data

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crash, schannel

I have a Point of Sale System developed by a local developer and I keep getting this error. The error results when I am using the program and hit the next button to display the next list of items in the menu. The program just crashes and closes when this occurs. The Program works though a mysql database that is running on the same computer.

Heres what my event viewer reported on the error.

> EVENT ID:36876
>   Source: Schannel
>   The certificate received from the remote server has not validated correctly. The error code is 0x80092013. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

Comment: What does the developer of the application say?

Comment: Hes not around anymore. The program has no log report system in place that I know about either.

Comment: Do you have the source code?  What server is the application trying to connect to?  Is it just the database or something else?  Is it your server?

Comment: its a database that i have access to. But no i dont have the source code.